# Message Not Understood for existing method

Tags: exception, smalltalk, pharo, method-declaration, missingmethod

Ok, so it's like this:

```
receiver selectors
```

returns

```
#(#expression #expression: #mondrianLabel #accept: #name)
```

But

```
receiver expression
```

throws `MessageNotUnderstood`.

Any ides how to fix this and why this can be caused?

Comment: I think you best clarify your question by changing `statement` to `receiver`. This is a more appropriate naming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably sending the message `expression` to a class instead of an instance of that class.

If the result of evaluating `receiver selectors` is `#(#expression #expression: #mondrianLabel #accept: #name)` then `receiver` is most probably a class. The message `#selectors` is implemented on the class `Behavior` and returns the selectors of the instance methods of the class. In other words: instances of the class (or any of its subclasses) understand the messages listed.

Hence, if you evaluate `receiver expression`, then you will get a *message not understood* exception because the message `#expression` is defined on the instance of the class that is the value of your `receiver` variable.

Comment: Thank. I've figured it out myself 5mins after posting a question, but before that I've spent about half a hour investigating…